# printar json api

Tags: php, json

estou querendo printar um dado q e em json porem quando abro no navegador ele abre diferente do q vejo eu estou usando o print_r queria saber como que se faz codigo

```
<?php
    $json='{"1":"a"}';

print_r(json_decode($json));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como queria q ficasse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: echo json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); isso que está procurando?

Comment: echo json_encode($json)  o JSON_PRETTY_PRINT é pra deixar mais bonito, só que não estou com tempo de explicar em uma resposta, mas tem alguns outro parâmetros possível pra deixar mais bonito a formatação

Comment: @BrunoH. acho q você n conseguiu entender se eu dou o comanto ele me retorna ""{\"1\":\"a\"}"" e eu queria que ele retornasse igual a imagem de baixo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa exibição é responsabilidade do navegador quando recebe uma resposta JSON do servidor. Não são todos os navegadores que exibem assim.

Por exemplo, ao acessar https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users no Firefox é exibido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já no Chrome é exibido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que faz ativar essa exibição no Firefox é o cabeçalho `Content-Type` da resposta do servidor, quando esse indica que é uma resposta JSON.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, para ativar essa exibição no Firefox basta você enviar a resposta JSON:

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(...);
```